# How to synchronize Eclipse project workspace with Git-BitBucket?

Tags: eclipse, git

I am new to Eclipse as well as Git world. Following question may sound like really dumb thing to ask, but I have spent hours finding how to do it and found no way.

We have a Git remote repository that I have cloned using Eclipse's Git perspective. My team makes some changes to code and pushes them to remote repository. I am stuck with "getting latest" code in my local workspace.

Here is what I tried:
Open Java EE perspective. Right click on my project -> Team -> Synchronize Workspace. This opens "Team Synchronizing" perspective. It shows me that there are some "incoming" files, but there is no option to "get" them. Only options I see are Merge, Overwrite, Commit. Well, none of them make sense to me.

In TFS world, I just select "get latest" and new versions replace old versions in local workspace. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Synchronize View](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Synchronize_View) will only allow you to inspect the differences between the resources in the local workspace and a local or remote tracking branch.

It won't get the last commits.

For that, you need to [pull new changes from the upstream branch](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Pulling_New_Changes_from_Upstream_Branch)

> Right-click on a project in the `Package Explorer` and select `Team > Pull` or right-click on a repository in the Git Repositories view and select `Pull` to pull new changes from the upstream branch your local branch is tracking.
>   This also works if resources are selected from more than one repository.

See for instance "[EGit Auto-Merge and Conflict Resolution](https://wiki.52north.org/Documentation/ResolveMergeConflictsInGitEclipse) "

[image: https://wiki.52north.org/pub/Documentation/ResolveMergeConflictsInGitEclipse/egit_merge_2.png]

To understand more about that workflow, look at [GIT Illustrated Cheatsheet -- Working with remote repositories](https://illustrated-git.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#working-with-remote-repositories)

[image: https://illustrated-git.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/git-flows.svg]